# How to make strip td in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to make strip `td` with different `background-color` using CSS?

```css
.backgroundi:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: #3366CC;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.backgroundi:nth-of-type(n+1) {
  background-color: #775577;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
  <td>
    <div class="backgroundi"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FdVEcrQtkyapUsmft8lw?p=preview)

Comment: There is a lot of information out there about how to do this already - https://www.google.co.uk/#q=css+zebra+table

Comment: You have a typo in your plnkr `<table clas="co">` should be `<table class="co">` also swap the css `.backgroundi` to `.co` - example `.co tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #775577; height: 60px; width: 60px;}`   http://plnkr.co/edit/cjMElvMiI2ejMkvhDHAx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

First, I dont know your code is complete or not but you need to add `<table> </table>` tag and put your code code inside the tag.
Now here is the code sample for you.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ffb3b3}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #E2E2E2}
```

```html
<table>
<tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
<td ><div class="backgroundi">background</div></td>
<td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margtop:25px">hello</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margtop:25px">test</div></td>
<td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margtop:25px">test STRIPE</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, what is going here is we are pointing odd and even rows for table and applying css on them. Parent class is table. Try this and all the best. Happy Coding :)

Comment: The full source is given in the plnkr link, the source code is complete with `<table>` tags.

Comment: @sumit almost every answer given here are prior to that with the same code/info having a few of them better info

Comment: @dippas i was in hurry and found same code as mine one so its useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
table tr td:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
table tr td:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
</style>

<table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: what about some explanation on how the code works? and how about using the OP actual code?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate the backgrounds of `<tr>` and of `<td>` in `<tr>`:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) > td:first-child{
    background-color: #3366CC; height:60px;width:60px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) > td:last-child{
    background-color: #775577; height: 60px; width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: is this an answer or a question to the OP?

Comment: It's an answer to the question. I wasn't entirely clear on what the OP was asking so am asking for some confirmation from the OP. I would have done in a comment but I can't yet write a comment under a question.

Answer (score 0):

Few changes in your code. hope this solves your problem.

```css
/* Styles go here */
tr td:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #3366CC; height:60px;width:60px;
   }
  tr td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #775577; height: 60px; width: 60px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table clas="co ">
                <tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                </tr><tr    ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" >
                  <td ><div></div></td>
                  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
  <td ><div></div></td>
  <td><div class="c" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:25px">hello</div></td>
                </tr>
                
              </table>
```